# "He's dead, Jim": Which Star Trek characters have returned from the dead?

Tags: star-trek

Among the recurring themes in Star Trek seems to be the alleged death of a character, who is later brought back to life.

It seems like this happens to a **lot** of major characters, though I cannot clearly recollect them all now. Which characters have either died, been pronounced dead, or were otherwise believed dead, only to later return?

For the purpose of this question copies of the allegedly deceased from alternate realities/timelines count but holograms of them do not (e.g. Kes didn't come back to life). All Star Trek films and series count. Some characters allegedly died, more than once I think. Might be worth noting.

Here are the ones I can think of offhand:

- **Spock** - died at least once at the end of the 2nd Star Trek movie; resurrected via  *fal-tor-pan*
- **Kirk** - believed dead after falling into the Nexus, brought back by Picard and killed shortly later; I'm 99% sure he died and came back a few times prior to this
- **Harry Kim** - replaced by a copy of himself from an alternate reality that had branched off minutes/hours earlier
- **Neelix** - brought back to life after 18 hours of death, Neelix was saved by injections of Borg nanoprobes
- **Dr. McCoy** - Impaled by a Knight's lance. He got better.
- **Scotty** - believed dead, but he was actually hiding in a transporter buffer.

I'm sure Picard should be on the list but I can't remember the specific details (assimilation doesn't count).

Comment: Wasn't janeway "dead" also where she thought she was in an in between realm?

Comment: If Harry Kim counts then Naomi Wildman does so as well. Died shortly after being born, replaced by a copy.

Comment: If you do count time travel episodes, then a lot of people "died" several times. Including both the entire TNG and the VOY crews.

Comment: Miles O'Brien dies in the episode Visionary in DS9 when the station is destroyed and his future self returns. [http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Visionary_(episode)]

Comment: @Hans Very good point.

Comment: +1 for "Neelix" becoming "Netflix". :-)

Comment: There was the episode in TNG when Picard died due to a fault with his artificial heart. Q took him back in time to avoid a fight with some nasty aliens when he was a cadet, during which he was impaled through the heart. With his real heart intact he lived on but was only a lieutenant when he returned to the present, so Q changed things back and Picard survived after all.

Comment: Picard killed himself once.  Does that count?

Comment: @jwodder Sure, when was that?

Comment: @Hack-R: ["Time Squared"](http://memory-alpha.wikia.com/wiki/Time_Squared_(episode))

Comment: Pretty much *Everyone*! Their body was destroyed by a transporter and a new identical one created in another location ;)

Comment: @Adwaenyth And even without time travel nor alternate universes you had the entire crew of the Voyager die (and then show up at the end of the episode).

Comment: So, I have two clarifications for this: both involving Data. One's specific, and one is more general.

Comment: Specific: I initially wanted to include "Time's Arrow (parts 1 and 2)" for Data, as the beginning of part 1 starts with discovering Data's head underneath San Francisco. Everyone in the episode believes Data is going to die. And eventually, Data does have his head severed. However, LaForge simply reattaches the "found" head to Data's body when it get's severed and he ends up being right as rain. Is that Data "dying" and "being brought back"?

Comment: This leads to the general question: Every time there's a large malfunction of some type with Data that causes him to deactivate, does that count as Data "dying"? What about if someone simply switches him off? Is he "dead"?

Comment: the transporter and the [Ship of theseus](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/search?q=ship+of+theseus) thing?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

## The Original Series

#### Lt. Commander Benjamin Finney

Supposedly killed during an ion storm the the *Star Trek TOS* episode *Courtmartial*. In fact, survived and hid on Enterprise during whole trial.

#### Kodos

Presumed dead 2246, actually masquerading as Anton Karidian. Discovered in 2266.
See *Star Trek TOS* episode *The Conscience of the King*

#### Spock

- Died at least once at the end of *Star Trek II: The Wrath of Kahn*; resurrected via fal-tor-pan.
- May have died in “Return to Tomorrow”.

#### Kirk

Believed dead after falling into the Nexus, brought back by Picard and killed shortly later.

Spock "killed" Kirk twice in the original series:

- In *The Enterprise Incident*, Spock used a "Vulcan death grip" to fool the Roumulans into believing he had killed Kirk.
- In *Amok Time*, Spock believed he *actually* killed Kirk during a battle to the death, though it was just a trick played by McCoy.

Also in the original series, Kirk was MIA and officially declared dead while he was lost in "interspace" in *The Tholian Web*.

Kirk died saving the Enterprise in Star Trek Into Darkness. He was revived by an injection of Khan's blood.

#### Dr. McCoy

Impaled by a Knight's lance in “Shore Leave”. He got better.

#### Scotty

- Believed dead, but he was actually hiding in a transporter buffer.
- He was killed (and then repaired) by Nomad in "The Changeling".

#### Chekov

Shot in a gunfight in “Spectre of the Gun”.  It was only an illusion.

## The Next Generation

#### Data

Thought to be dead but actually just kidnapped and his death faked by the kidnapper.

Presumed dead and subsequently buried by silly locals in "To Thine Own Self" actually just needed to be switched on.

#### Geordi LaForge

Presumed dead but actually just "out of phase" with everything except the floors of the *Enterprise*.

#### Ro Laren

Presumed dead but actually just "out of phase" with everything except the floors of the *Enterprise*.

#### Tasha Yar

Killed by a black ooze (*Skin of Evil*), then brought back to life by an alteration in the time line (*Yesterday's Enterprise*). Survived the putting of the timeline back to normal (evidence of this in *Redemption*).

#### Yareena

In the first season episode "Code of Honor" of *Star Trek: The Next Generation*, Yareena gets killed after a fight, but is revived on the *Enterprise*.

#### Worf

In the first season episode "Hide and Q" he is stabbed to death with a bayonet by one of the alien creatures conjured by Q. He is brought back to life with the power of the Q by William Riker.

Worf also dies in the *TNG* episode "[Ethics](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Ethics_(episode)#Act_Five)". Worf breaks his back at the start of the episode, and undergoes an experimental procedure that results in him dying. After several minutes, Worf's "backup" biological functions end up reviving him.

#### Wesley Crusher

In the first season episode "Hide and Q" he is also stabbed to death with a bayonet after rushing to aid Worf. He is brought back to life with the power of the Q by William Riker.

## Deep Space 9

#### Miles O'Brien

Miles O'Brien has been replaced by future self in the episode ["Visionary"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Visionary_(episode)) after dying because of the contamination.

Additionally, O'Brien's death was faked by T'Lani and Kellerun ambassadors in ["Armageddon Game"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Armageddon_Game_(episode)), but ultimately he was found alive and rescued, along with Dr. Bashir (see below).

#### Dr. Julian Bashir

Dr. Bashir's death was faked by T'Lani and Kellerun ambassadors in ["Armageddon Game"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Armageddon_Game_(episode)), but ultimately he was found alive and rescued, along with Miles O'Brien (see above).

### Morn

Morn fakes his own death in [“Who Mourns for Morn”](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Who_Mourns_for_Morn%3F_(episode)), and turns up alive at the end of the episode.

## Voyager

#### Janeway

In the third season episode "Coda" of *Star Trek: Voyager*, Captain Janeway is brought back to life by Chakotay after crash landing with a shuttle.

#### Harry Kim

Replaced by a copy of himself from an alternate reality that had branched off minutes/hours earlier.
He also really died in "Emanations" (Season 1), brought back to life shortly after.

#### Naomi Wildman

Like Harry, a copy of her from a recently deviated reality replaced her dead self in the main reality.

#### Neelix

Brought back to life after 18 hours of death, Mr. Neelix was saved by injections of Borg nanoprobes.

#### Ensign Lyndsay Ballard / Jhet'leya

In "Ashes to Ashes" (Season 6), we learn that Ensign Lyndsay Ballard, who had died, was resurrected by the Kobali.

## Enterprise

#### Jonathan Archer

When the *Enterprise* reached Azati Prime (*Azati Prime*) Captain Jonathan Archer chose to undertake a suicide mission in order to complete the Xindi mission. T'Pol's emotional reaction toward Archer's departure and presumed death incapacitated her as a commanding officer (ending up with crying and an attempt to recover him).

#### Crewman Daniels

Apparently disintegrated by Silik in ["Cold Front"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cold_Front_(episode)) (*ENT* 1x11), his appearances in later episodes were likely due to temporal manipulation or advanced technology.

## Footnotes

#### The entire crew of *Voyager*, except for Chakotay and Kim

The *Voyager* crashed into an ice planet on the edge of the Alpha quadrant, while Kim and Chakotay in the Delta Flyer got back to Earth. 15 years later, Chakotay managed to send a message to Seven of Nine's implants to warn them of the crash before it happened.

#### Dinosaurs

The *Voyager* crew discovered that dinosaurs were actually not extinct, but had become a highly evolved, technological, race living in the Delta quadrant, whose sophistication was limited only by indoctrination of their society by those in power as a means of protecting their grip on power.

#### The entire complement of The *Enterprise-D*

The *Enterprise* was destroyed with all hands, repeatedly, in [TNG: Cause and Effect](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Cause_and_Effect_(episode)). Then, it wasn't destroyed for a while.

#### The entire population of Earth in the 22nd Century

In the original timeline of ["Twilight"](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/Twilight_(episode)) (*ENT* 3x08), the Xindi superweapon attack succeeded, destroying Earth in a matter of seconds.  Everyone on Earth died, presumably including named characters such as Admiral Forrest.  A number of series regulars died in a later battle.  A change to the timeline prevented all of these deaths.

#### All Earth-descended life (and likely all life in Earth's quadrant of the galaxy)

The anomaly in ["All Good Things..."](https://memory-alpha.fandom.com/wiki/All_Good_Things..._(episode)) (*TNG* 7x25/26) prevented life from developing on Earth. Since the anomaly encompassed Earth's quadrant of the galaxy, it likely also interfered with the development of life on other worlds.

Comment: I've made this a community wiki so anyone can edit the answer.

Comment: Many of these characters didn't return from the dead, so I don't get why you included them.

Comment: Does it count that Kirk was thought dead in Amok Time?

Comment: @T-1000'sSon Could you be more specific? Does your comment take into consideration the guidelines laid out in the question?

Comment: @SQB Yes, I think Tasha should count. When the list becomes more complete perhaps we can organize it into sections like "time travel related", etc.

Comment: @Hack-R or organised by series.

Comment: The ---Abramsverse--- Kelvin Timeline adds at least a couple, if that fits. Sarek and Amanda die in the prime timeline, are alive in *Star Trek*(2009). Then again, it was at a point in time when they were alive in the prime timeline, as well. I hate temporal mechanics.

Comment: What about Tuvix? Neelix and Tuvok ceased to exist until Tuvix was split. Not exactly death, per se... Also, Data again in "Time's Arrow" when they re-attach his past head to his current body.

Comment: @miltonaut Sure, add it. Let's be inclusive.

Comment: I appreciate the "everything but the floors".

Comment: How about "Miles O'Brien, about once a season on DS9"?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wasn't Chekov killed in Spectre of the Gun (aka the trippy episode where they fight at the OK Corral?), and later returned to life by the alien beings who created the struggle?

Comment: I know everyone abhors the episode and no one wants to think of it - but is being turned into a lizard while using an experimental transwarp drive the same thing as being dead?

Comment: No but he was clinically dead for a bit in that episode now that you mention it.

Comment: Does the Miles O'Brien replicant in Whispers count?

Comment: I'd take exception to the inclusion of Finney who never actually died. You can't come back from a condition you were never in.

Comment: Yeah, man the out of phase except for the floors thing with LaForge and Rolan always bothered me.

Comment: Apparently Riker died in the lost timeline of Yesterday's Enterprise?  Was time-shenanigans retconned almost immediately.

Comment: Also, the entry on Johnathan Archer doesn't really explain how he became not-dead.

Comment: Technically every future generation died before the Xindi attack, before they invented warp drive, in First Contact earth was assimilated in the past, and as the Borg don't reproduce then there would be no more births beyond that point either

Answer (score 0):

Worf also died if I'm not mistaken in TNG by a being who was evolving into pure energy. His neck was broke when energy from the humanoid pushed him off the platform to a lower level in a roundabout cargo bay. He was healed and brought back to life by the same humanoid.

Comment: It would help a lot if you could cite the episode in question.  Is it possible you're conflating the 2 episodes listed in the previous answer where Worf dies?

Comment: He didn't die, he was just paralyzed iirc - that episode would be S3 Transfigurations: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transfigurations

Comment: @NKCampbell - I would be inclined to agree (and he's survived a broken neck before), but the Doctor scanned him and indicated 'No Life Signs' which is fairly conclusive.

Comment: ah true @K-H-W - however, Crusher never declares him dead she summons a resuscitation team, meaning there's still a chance : D  #semantics - maybe Worf can write a book "90 Minutes in Sto-vo-kor: I Met Fek'lhr"

Comment: @NKCampbell However, even today we can sometimes resuscitate people who are "medically dead", with no life signs.  So, yes he's dead - but only *mostly* dead.